# Making a file name that contains quotes and slashes

Tags: terminal

how is it possible to create a file with a name similar to `"\?$*’KzUmi’*$?\"` from terminal? I have tried to escape it using double quotes and \ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add single quotes, for example:

```
$ mkdir '?$*’KzUmi’*$?'
```

To `cd` into it could then use:

```
$ cd '?$*’KzUmi’*$?'
```

or by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> probably your shell would escape it to:

```
$ cd \?\$\*’KzUmi’\*\$\?
```

Comment: @HiThere sure, give a try `touch '?$*’KzUmi’*$?'`

Comment: I just tried it, it still missing the \ and the '' " on the sides.

Comment: working from my side using `zsh`, give a try to `touch "\"\\?\$*’KzUmi’*\$?\\\""`